# Using DateTool in jar: how to specify toolbox

Tags: java, velocity

I'm using velocitytools inside a jar to generate some files.
Now I'd like to use the DateTools and MathTools within my templates.
But how do I add these since there's no web-inf folder inside my jar project where it will automatically scan, nor have I found a function yet to programmatically set the location/add the tool.

Neither

```
Velocity.setApplicationAttribute("dateTool", new DateTool());
```

nor

```
Velocity.setProperty("dateTool", new DateTool());
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this into `VelocityContext`:

```
VelocityContext ctx = new VelocityContext();
ctx.put("dateTool", new DateTool());
```